# Dark mode in TeX Stack Exchange

Tags: discussion, design, user-interface

I just realised that there is an option for dark mode for Stack Overflow. I was wondering if there is any chance our community could use it too.

Comment: As a switch so that each user can decide for him/herself I guess?

Comment: Is the dark mode available for the TeX Exchange Community too? I think it's only available for the Stack Overflow and not for the whole Stack Exchange.

Comment: I don't think it is, yet. They are in beta only on overflow (I guess). My first comment was on how this works. In the meantime I found it on SO.

Comment: Just use Dark Reader extension...

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. Yeah, that's what I do. My recommendation for Firefox is "Dark Background and Light Text": simple and flexible

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is being tested on [Stack Overflow](//stackoverflow.com) only. Plans to roll this out to all networks across Stack Exchange is currently unlikely as each graduated site has its own design elements that might not fit well with a universal dark mode switch. I would assume each site would have to initiate its own poll to see whether it would warrant the time to come up with a site-specific dark mode option. This, however, is all dependent on how well dark mode on Stack Overflow is utilised once the kinks have been sorted out.

Source: [The Overflow: Introducing Dark Mode (beta) for Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/03/30/introducing-dark-mode-for-stack-overflow/)

Comment: Any update on this? Thanks

Comment: @jessexknight: A [post on Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/378976/168244) mentions the SE workload looking forward. They mention a backlog of roughly 100 site redesigns that have come out beta before they do anything else (including bringing more accessibility and customization ~ dark mode - to other sites. Personally, I think this will take a while.